# .NET MVC + Dojo (Other Framework) for mini-ERP

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, dojo, javascript-framework

We are about to develop a mini-ERP web-app. We need the app to be browser agnostic with rich user interface which should be 'enterprise-ready'!. [Something like the latest openERP](https://demo.my.openerp.com/?db=demo_1310457809&user=demo&password=demo&login_action=login).

We are planning on using the .NET MVC 3 and Dojo for our project.

So our major queries are:

1. Are there any Htmlhelpers for Dojo. Any opensource implementation where we can get some idea.
2. Will the app be slow if we use Dojo? In our previous project we integrated Dojo with PHP and had to make the web-app SPA (single page application). This is because on each request, the declarative markup was processed by dojo. So larger the no. of widgets, longer the processing. We had not tried the Dojo build feature then. Will that make it fast? Or do we have to go with the Single Page Application? What are the pro/cons of SPA?

Note: We are open to using any other competitive JS Framework. Bonus point if we get some ready implementation with .NET MVC (for reference).

Comment: Dojo really excels for SPA's.  For MVC-type apps in a SPA manner, you can look into the dojox.mvc sub-project.  Considering that you want to do an ERP system, SPA's really makes sense for you.  Is there any reason why you need to serve individual pages for updated screens (which you can easily use ASP.NET MVC 3) -- you're right, those will be slower for Dojo on the client side, but faster on the server side.

Comment: We've been using MVC3 + Dojo on our project and now that we are approaching our first customer demo, we are ripping it out.  It just does not mix with MVC3 well.  For example the date picker formats dates in an IEEE format so you have to create your own widget that "inherits" from the stock datepicker. The upgrade from 1.7 to 1.8 had lots of breaking changes so we had to roll back. Now we are using jQuery UI that comes with MVC3 and things are going much faster.  Dojo has been in transition to version 1.8 and it's hard to find good examples. support is via #IRC chat. It's mostly a bummer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have developed ERP application using ASP.NET MVC 2. It is not so advanced but it gets the job done.

Here are some points concerning its implementation:

- It is not SPA
- For the UI I have used jQueryUI and [jqGrid](http://www.trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/jqgrid.html), which perform very well
- AJAX form submission using [jQuery Form Plugin](http://jquery.malsup.com/form/)

Answer (score 0):

We are using ASP.NET MVC4 in our ERP project. These features are related with the architecture .

- JQuery Layout
- SlickGrid (a open source grid control with very rich functions and plugins)
- ZTree
- JQuery Dialog
- WebApi (not WCF)
- Dapper (not EntityFramework)

We combine many plugins working together, and one team member is familiar with CSS and DIV layout. There are some challenges if you haven't rich experience with javascript and UI layout. Finally, we have completed the project, it is amazing.